# Understanding Code Flow For Setting State in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, state

I have this basic code which updates a state from a handler:

```
const wait = (ms) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
};

export default function App() {
  async function handleClick() {
    setData(1);
    console.log("first click");
    console.log(data);
    await wait(1000);
    setData(2);
    console.log("second click");
    console.log(data);
  }

  const [data, setData] = React.useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      {data}&nbsp;
      <button onClick={() => handleClick(setData)}>Click Me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am trying to understanding the order of operations, could someone please verify or point me in the right direction of what is happening? I have researched around but haven't found conclusive sources on what I think is happening.

1. we click the button, triggering the handler
2. the handler runs `setData(1)`, enqueuing a task to the event loop
3. `console.log('first click')` runs
4. we log the state (data), which is still 0, as the setter has only been enqueued
5. we run into the wait function, so we exit out to the synchronous code flow as we wait for the 1000ms
6. the sync code finishes running, so we dequeue the next task, which is the setter function, the state is now set to 1, and the view re-renders and reflects that new state
7. after 1 second has elapsed, we return to the code after wait function
8. `setData(2)` enqueues another task
9. 'second click' is logged
10. 0 is stil logged, as our local state has not changed
11. the sync code finishes, we dequeue the setter, re-rendering the view, causing 2 to show up

Is this all correct? Have I misunderstood anything? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you've got this down correctly, except possibly for the bit

> runs `setData(1)`, enqueuing a task to the event loop

This may or may not involve the event loop. What happens in `setData` is specific to react.js, and won't necessarily enqueue a task in the *browser* event loop. It certainly does "somehow" schedule the state update and re-rendering of the component - within react.

If I remember correctly, react.js does schedule the render caused by `setData(1)` for the end of the native click handler, i.e. when the call to your `onClick` handler returns to react code. And for `setData(2)`, the rendering might actually happen synchronously within the `setData` call, as react does not control the context. This is however subject to change (the devs are talking about batching multiple updates together asynchronously) and should be considered an implementation detail. If you're curious, just place a `console.log` in the render function of your component, but do not write any code that relies on the order observed in this test!

Comment: Makes perfect sense and thank you SO much for going through it. I actually had a bit in there about if it was truly async but removed it for brevity.